# Last update timestamp with JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I'm playing around a bit with JPA(Eclipselink to be specific). The below entity have a 
timestamp that's supposed to reflect whenever that entity was last updated.

What are the strategies for making JPA update that timestamp automatically every time
this entity is changed ?

How would I go about if I also want a 'creation' timestamp, only set when the entity is first persisted, never allowed to be changed again ?

```
 @Entity
 public class Item implements Serializable {
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
     private Integer id;
     private String note;


    public Item () {
    }


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=SEQUENCE)
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    @Column(length=255)
    @Column(nullable=false)
    public String getNote() {
        return this.note;
    }

    public void setNote(String note) {
        this.note = note;
    }

    @Column(nullable=false)
    public Timestamp getUpdated() {
        return this.updated;
    }

    public void setUpdated(Timestamp updated) {
        this.updated = updated;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [@PrePersist](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/PrePersist.html) and [@PreUpdate](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/PreUpdate.html) annotations and write your own event listener.

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725699/hard-time-setting-autogenerated-time-with-hibernate-jpa-annotations/1726375#1726375) for details. It's tagged as Hibernate but is applicable to any JPA provider.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using mysql, I think you can do the following to disable the timestamps from being updated from entity

```
@Column(name = "lastUpdate", updatable= false, insertable=false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date lastUpdate;
```

for oracle you time have to set the timestamps from the entity using @PreUpdate annotation as explained above.

Comment: This is wrong for many reasons: (1) the above assumes that you're manually updating the timestamp thus setting "updatable" is pointless; (2) consequently, the above will not work without @PreUpdate / @PrePersist event listeners; (3) if you want database to generate your timestamps (which you seem to imply), you have to mark your properties as generated which is **not** in JPA standard; (4) finally, MySQL will not let you have 2 auto-updated timestamps in the same table.

Comment: Regarding mysql, you can create one or more triggers to update any number of columns such as a timestamp - you are not limited to 1 auto updated timestamp in a table.

Comment: in MySql you can also create table with 2 timestamps and insert NULL on both field when inserting a record.

    create table ts ( 
    last_updated_ts TIMESTAMP, 
    created_ts TIMESTAMP, 
    name varchar(5) );
insert into ts(last_updated_ts, created_ts, name) value (null, null, 'test');

Definitely trigger or annotation is better depending on how the client accesses the database.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, **surajz** answer works. Consider a scenario where you are tracking 2 timestamps. You want to manually update them via the entity. You'd need to set one to `updateble=false` (the one you do not want updated when the record is updated), and leave the other free for updates.

That's what worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In Entity class

```
@Column
@UpdateTimestamp
private Timestamp updatedOn

@Column
@CreationTimestamp
private Timestamp createdOn
```

it will update automatically when any change in entity

Supported attribute types

```
java.time.LocalDate (since Hibernate 5.2.3)
java.time.LocalDateTime (since Hibernate 5.2.3)
java.util.Date
java.util.Calendar
java.sql.Date
java.sql.Time
java.sql.Timestamp
```

Example :

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
 
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Timestamp createdOn;
 
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Timestamp updatedOn;
 
}
```