# How does Play!'s Comet support work?

Tags: comet, playframework

I saw the Akka module's description says that [Play](http://playframework.org) has great Comet support, but I've never used [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) before and I can't find any mention of it in Play's documentation.  How does it work in Play?

---

I spent a few hours over two days figuring this out so I wanted to share this info for other Play beginners.

Comment: Don't put "solved" in the title, just mark your own answer as accepted.

Comment: Those good old days when forums were the source for answers and getting a `[solved] was a victory over endless frustration :D

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Play includes a sample Chat application which demonstrates how to use Comet.  The example doesn't explain what's going on though, so here's what I've figured out.

### Model

In order for others to find new updates you send, they'll need to be stored somewhere.  Conceivably this could be in a cache or even in the controller itself, but the database is going to be the safest bet, so you'll want a model. They'll also need a way to determine *which* updates are new to them, which means you'll probably want a date field (see also: [Last update timestamp with JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745890/last-update-timestamp-with-jpa)).  The Chat example uses a simple model:

```
@Entity
public class Message extends Model {     
    public String user;
    public Date date;
    public String text;

    public Message(String user, String text) {
        this.user = user;
        this.text = text;
        this.date = new Date();
    }       
}
```

### Controller

The controller needs two methods to facilitate Comet.  One where new data is posted, which doesn't do anything special:

```
public static void postMessage(String message) {
    new Message(session.get("nick"), message).save();
}
```

and one for retrieving updates:

```
public static void newMessages() {
    List<Message> messages = Message.find("date > ?", request.date).fetch();
    if (messages.isEmpty()) {
        suspend("1s");
    }
    renderJSON(messages);
}
```

The key bit here is `suspend("1s")` which is what holds the HTTP request open, checking for new data once per second.

### View

The view has three responsibilities -- sending new data, fetching updates and then rendering those updates.

Sending, like the corresponding controller action, doesn't do anything special:

```
$('#send').click(function(e) {
    var message = $('#message').val();
    $('#message').val('');
    $.post('@{postMessage()}', {message: message}); 
});
```

Fetching updates is the magic bit:

```
// Retrieve new messages
var getMessages = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@{newMessages()}',
        success: function(messages) {
            $(messages).each(function() {
                display(this);
            });
        },
        complete: function() {
            getMessages();
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}
getMessages();
```

`getMessages()` is called once to get things started, and afterwards it calls itself recursively after each successful request.  It GETs the `newMessages()` action which looks for new messages, and if there aren't any it holds the request open until it has something to report.  When new messages are found, the JSON data is passed to a `display` function:

```
var display = function(message) {
    $('#thread').append(tmpl('message_tmpl', {message: message}));
}
```

The `display` function applies a [JavaScript Micro-Template](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/) to the JSON data to render new messages.  Use of micro templates isn't necessary, but it does work pretty well.  They're included right in the template of the page that's going to use them:

```
<script type="text/html" id="message_tmpl">
    <div class="message <%= message.user == '${session.nick}' ? 'you' : '' %> <%= message.user == 'notice' ? 'notice' : '' %>">
        <h2><%= message.user %></h2>
        <p><%= message.text.replace('\n', '<br/>') %></p>
    </div>
</script>
```

The `type="text/html"` causes browsers, search engines and screen readers to ignore the whole `script` block.  The result is much easier to read and maintain than using jQuery to build nodes or concatenating strings.  Overall it's pretty simple once you know which bits are relevant.

Comment: Are you sure that this has anything to do with the comet-framework? I thought it was only native solution.

Comment: @niels - I'm not sure what you mean, especially since I'm just starting with this, but Comet is an umbrella term for sending updates to clients, and this is how Play accomplishes it.

Comment: you are right. I thought that there was an existing framework named comet.

Comment: this seems like I can call Java functions from the javascript code. What's this:  $.post('@{postMessage()}', {message: message});

Comment: @lhk it's not calling javascript from java; Java is actually being used to generate javascript. In this case, the template engine is inserting the url for posting new messages. If you were to 'View Source' on the page, you'd see something like `$.post('/messages', {message: message});`

Comment: @bemace you've just opened my eyes: I've tried to find a way to get database updates synced with the javascript GUI. Querying for changes from javascript is easy - Initiating an update from the server isn't. Now I'll just regenerate the javascript part each time the database is changed. That means there will be no HTTP Request at all to trade parameters

Comment: wouldn't you get a JavaScript stack overflow? JavaScript has no tail recursion optimization.

Answer (score 7):

There are many ways to achieve **server-push** or Comet in web applications, and one of the most common is Long Polling due to it being well supported in most modern browsers.

Play achieves long polling mainly through the `suspend(time);` function. This function does two very important things

1. it keeps the HTTP request open and retries the action in the time specified. This allows you to hold the HTTP request and keep retrying the action until something has happened that you want to inform the browser about
2. and very importantly, the thread is released when the request is suspended. This means that the http request does not hold an open thread for each suspended request.

When play is in DEV mode, it only runs on a single thread, yet you can (and I have tried) run dozens of users on the sample chat application without the server hanging, or users getting blocked requests.

The suspend method however is the only thing that play really does to help with Comet. If you run the sample chat application and leave a client open, you will notice that after 120 seconds, the request will timeout. The sample application does not re-try the request. The client side of the long-polling technology you have to build yourself.

Guillaume has mentioned in the forums that the sample chat application is just a demo of how long polling can be used. So I don't think Play can attest to having great Comet support, it is just a step in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  The only info I was able to find regarding Play and Comet was what the [akka author said](http://www.playframework.org/modules/akka-head/home).

Comment: Where's your 120s figure from?  I just tried leaving sessions of my app (modeled after the Chat example) in Firefox and Chrome idle for 30 minutes and both still worked.  Chrome even indicates it with it's spinner.  Firefox did miss updates a couple times during my testing though.

Comment: It may have been IE. it seemed to timeout after a certain length of time. Some proxies an loadbalancers I have seen do a similar timeout.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Mist in Akka for server-push (Comet) backed with Servlet 3.00 or Jetty7 Continuations: http://doc.akkasource.org/http#Mist%20-%20Lightweight%20Asynchronous%20HTTP

Comment: Akka has switched to Play! 2.0 and Play-mini! 2.0 for Comet