# How can I get the current state of an entity which has been passed as an argument to a view scope managed bean method with EL?

Tags: jsf, jpa

I need to update an entity in my managed bean. I want to do this by passing this entity to a method in my managed bean with a `MethodExpression`, with `action` or `actionListener`, which seems like the easier and clearest way. I want the managed bean to have view scope because I'm using Primefaces' `dataTable` and it doesn't seem to call the action method when I change it to request scope (just my `preRenderView` listener).

```
<h:commandXXXX action="#{bean.method(entity)}">

@ManagedBean(name="bean")
@ViewScoped
class Bean {
    public void method(Entity entity) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The problem is, this entity might have been changed by another user or just the same user in another page. I could retrieve the entity from the database again and overwrite the argument, but this feels silly and ugly.

```
public void method(Entity entity) {
    entity = entityDAO.findById(entity.getId());
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? Would I have the newest state of the entity if I were to change the bean to request scope (assuming that I am able to make it work with the `dataTable`)?

Comment: You can put your entity in application scope

Comment: I admit that I just update from DB :-) but you might create another EJB layer that would hold the entity attached to the persistence context. In this case you will need to design the transactions properly.

Comment: This is not necessarily a JSF/Web app issue. Managing concurrent access to a single entity transcends the web application and into the data layer. **Do not put that entity (or any entity) in the application scope**.

Comment: This is a concurrency issue and you have some very interesting answers on that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564877/how-do-you-manage-concurrent-access-to-forms).  A very simple solution would be to add a [lastupdate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745890/last-update-timestamp-with-jpa) column to your entity and before saving you check if it has changed. If so, you reject the save.