# Transparently recording the last modified user on JPA entity

Tags: java, jpa

I have found the technique in the answer below very useful for transparently managing the created and updated timestamp for entities:

[hard time setting autogenerated time with hibernate JPA annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725699/hard-time-setting-autogenerated-time-with-hibernate-jpa-annotations/1726375#1726375)

I am wondering if there is something similar for recording the create and update user for the entity?

```
@PreUpdate
@PrePersist
public void updateAudit() {
    lastModifiedDate = new Date();
    lastModifiedUser = ??;
    if (dateCreated==null) {
      dateCreated = new Date();
      userCreated = ??;
    }
}
```

While new `Date()` in the example provides the current time, I am having trouble finding a location in which the user id could be stored (at logon time) which is accessible from a @PrePersist annotated method on an entity.

Injecting a `@LoggedInUser` with a `@Produces` method would be ideal but my entities are created by `new()` rather than by injection so are not managed.

I'm pretty new to this so I hope I'm missing something obvious. Thanks.

[edit] Answer below from prunge led to code (abridged)

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable, Comparable<BaseEntity> {

    @Version
    private Timestamp updatedTimestamp;

    private static ThreadLocal<Long> threadCurrentUserId = new ThreadLocal<Long>();

    /* Called from entry point like servlet 
    */
    public static void setLoggedInUser(BaseEntity user) {
        if (user!=null) threadCurrentUserId.set(user.getId());
    }

    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    protected void onCreateOrUpdate() {
         //Note we don't have to update updatedTimestamp    since the @Version annotation does it for us
         if(createdTimestamp==null) createdTimestamp = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());;

         lastUpdatedByUserId = threadCurrentUserId.get();
         if(createdByUserId==null)  createdByUserId = lastUpdatedByUserId;
    }
```

Comment: What user name are you looking to capture?  Is this a: web app?  fat client?  What, if any, security framework are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a webapp, you could use a ThreadLocal for storing the current user.

- Set the ThreadLocal value in a servlet filter, reading the user from servlet request.
- Read the ThreadLocal value from your JPA entities.
- Clear the value on the trip back through the filter.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually inject CDI dependencies using a custom CDI Injector, I think something along the lines of:

```
@Inject
private BeanManager beanManager;    

...

Entity entity = new Entity();

AnnotatedType<?> type = beanManager.createAnnotatedType(class);

InjectionTarget target = beanManager.createInjectionTarget(type);
CreationalContext context = beanManager.createCreationalContext(null);

target.inject(entity, context);
```

Note that the entity will not become a CDI managed bean but will get all its dependencies injected (and these will be managed by cdi).

Having said that, there is probably a better method to do it depending on the web/security frameworks you're using.